# Is 'IsolateScope' in Angularjs using $watch by default?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I don't understand why or why not angularjs isolated scope use or not $watch?

***For example:***

```
app.directive('fooDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            readonly: '=' or '@' or '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           // should I use $watch here or not ?
           scope.$watch('readonly', function () {
               // do I require to do so???
           });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Does it matter? I want to know if it's issued for that attribute or no? I mean if after scope isolation I will have two $watches or one?

Comment: by using `=` you activate the databinding whereas `@` is readonly, preferably for strings

Comment: In your case you have one watcher for `readonly` - the one you created - and one implicit watcher for whatever expression `readonly` is bound to.

Comment: Why the implicit $watch and can I disable it?

Comment: @zeroflagL can you answer the question, I will it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have HTML like this

```
<div foo-directive readonly="question.readonly">
```

The the following happens: `scope.readonly` within your directive gets the value of `question.readonly` (from outside the isolated scope). Whenever the value of `question.readonly` changes, the value of `scope.readonly` changes accordingly. You have nothing to do for that to happen.

But if you want to do something additionally whenever `scope.readonly` changes, like changing the color of an element when it's no longer read-only, the  you need your own watcher (`scope.$watch`).

Answer (score 0):

Isolated scopes and `$watch` is not the same. Using an isolated scope like

```
scope: {
    myAttr: '='
}
```

tells `$compile` to bind to the `my-attr=""` attribute. That means if you change the value in your *directive* it gets updated in the parent scope(s) as well.

On the other hand, using `$watch` triggers a function if that value changes.